# Test fails on Amazon and Codeship

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, groovy, google-api, codeship

Building an application using Dropbox and Google Drive in Groovy, the tests run fine.

Code:

```
 def "It instantiates and configures the googleAuthorizationCodeFlowBuilder component"() {
         given:
         def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
         GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder builder = ctx.googleAuthorizationCodeFlowBuilder

         expect:
 }
```

When running on Codeship and Amazon however, the test fails:

> Message: Error creating bean with name 'googleAuthorizationCodeFlowBuilder': 
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
>   Could not instantiate bean class [com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder]: 
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Line | Method
>   ->>  285 | autowireConstructor             in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver
>
> |   1075 | autowireConstructor             in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>
> /* stuff */
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild
>   |   1549 | call                            in     ''
>   |    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
>   |   1145 | runWorker                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>   |    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>   ^    745 | run                             in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder]: 
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ->>  163 | instantiateClass                in org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
>
> |    121 | instantiate                     in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
>   |    277 | autowireConstructor . . . . . . in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver
>   |   1075 | autowireConstructor             in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>   |    979 | createBeanInstance . . . . . .  in     ''
>   |    487 | doCreateBean                    in     ''
>   |    123 | doCreateBean . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>
> /* more stacktrace */
>
> |    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>   ^    745 | run                             in java.lang.Thread

The googleAuthorizationflowBuilder bean only creates a GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder (I use the Google java API).

EDIT 1: I reproduced the error on my machine by modifying doWithSpring:

```
def doWithSpring = {
        def config = application.config
        String googleSecret = getConfigValue(config, 'storage.google.secret')
        String googleAppId = null//getConfigValue(config, 'storage.google.appId')
        String appName = getConfigValue(config, 'storage.appName')

        if (!ConfigUtils.optional(config,'storage.google.disabled')) {
            googleNetHttpTransport(NetHttpTransport)
            googleJsonFactory(JacksonFactory)
            googleCredentialsBuilder(GoogleCredential.Builder) {
                transport = googleNetHttpTransport
                jsonFactory = googleJsonFactory
            }
       googleAuthorizationCodeFlowBuilder(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder, ref('googleNetHttpTransport'), ref('googleJsonFactory'),
                googleAppId, googleSecret, [DRIVE])
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2 : It seems that the error happen specifically when the AppId is null... The question is why is it null on the cloud and not on my machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that the environment variables used to initialize the values of Config.groovy weren't set on the Codebase project, resulting in the aforementioned error.

The missing environment variables have been initialized on Codeship and everything works great now.

Comment: Ahoy, Marko from the Codeship crew here. I just saw the message and wanted to ask if you already fixed this? If not, don't hesitate to get in touch via our in-app messenger or support@codeship.com!

Comment: @Marko It is fixed! Just a stupid error. The missing environment variables have been initialized and everything works great now.

Comment: Great, if you have any other questions, don't hesitate to get in touch! Cheers! :)